# Class that returns a value instead of self

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to make a class in `typescript` that when an instance of it is used, it returns a value or property instead of itself? E.g. `console.log(myClassInstance) => 1`

When I first tried to do this I thought maybe something like this would work:

```
class MyClass<T> {

    constructor(private a: T) {}

    get this() { return this.a }
}
```

But unfortunately it didn't. This worked: `myClassInstance.this => myClassInstance.a`, but that defeats the whole purpose. Is there any possible way to do this?

**Edit**

Some people asked about why i would want this, and it's simply for better readability. If i for example wanted a Matrix class, i could just use a nested array, but adding custom functions and properties to it would just be a hassle. Also, `new Matrix<number>()` looks way better than `new Array<Array<number>>`

I know i can make use of interfaces and functions to make it look like they create an instance of a class but instead returns another value: `new Matrix<number>() => new Array<Array<number>>()`, but i hope there is a better way using classes.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this over just using, say, a number?

Comment: @ScottSauyet what a silly question, it adds to ambiguity! And more ambiguous it is, the better! If it doesn't work on top of being ambiguous, mission accomplished - the project is now in the state that it requires constant maintenance and endless money and time hole is created, achieving what physicists at CERN didn't do so far - singularity.

Comment: @Mjh: oh, of course.  I should have realized.  Silly of me, really.

Comment: I think it's worth trying to explain why you would want this, because if you want an object to always be some other value when it's used, you should just use the other variable in the first place and skip the object altogether. You probably have a great motivation for this, so share that... there's probably a better way!

Comment: @Evert there wouldn't be a built in Object prototype for doing this if there wasn't a use for it. Not really intuitive to me either but it is there. I guess it could be handy say in a math lib

Comment: A Matrix object would probably also add methods to the underlying value, things such as `add`, `scalarMultiply`, `invert`, etc., as well as invariants (all row are the same length, etc.  This is definitely the province of a class.  You can use `valueOf` to return the underlying type if you want to be able to use it as one.

Comment: "*when an instance of it is used*" - then you usually want to work with the instance, not the wrapped array. Are you really doing this so often that it harms readability?

Comment: If you're sticking methods onto an existing type, why type it as a class constructor in the first place? Seems like it would be easier to do `createMatrix()` as a function, since you're not actually creating an instance of something class, just an array + some extra functions.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Then i would have to stick methots onto Array<Array<T>>, which i could do, but im looking for a better way

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Since you said you wanted to return a `value` instead of `self`, I understood that to mean that `value` would be the Array itself, with the methods stuck onto it. What else would `value` be if it can be neither a `self` instance nor an existing type with methods tacked on?

Comment: @loganfsmyth it would be an existing type that got returned

Comment: @Kris10an Can you please add more details to the question about what you actually want to do then? You've now said that you want to return an existing type that is different from the constructor fn type, but then also said you don't want to add methods onto an existing object, and presumable can't just add methods to the existing type instead of the constructor type. I don't think it is clear what you're expecting here, so noone is going to be able to answer.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I want to have a class, that when used returns a value (a number for example) instead of the actual instance object.

Comment: If the return value is just a number, there is no reason to use a class in the first place, you can just use a function. What is the motivation for wanting a class constructor when your objective isn't actually constructing an instance of that class?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) and specify what primitive you want returned

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(a) {this.a = a }
    valueOf() { return this.a }
}


const t = new MyClass(7)

console.log(+t)
```

Comment: Sure is cool, but it only works with numbers and doesn't really look too good. I could use this valueOf in other places though!

Comment: What were you hoping it would return? Should work for strings also. What is your use case?

Comment: I tried using it with strings but it just returned NaN. I edited the question now for clarity

Comment: That's because you use `+` to cast to number...string example https://jsfiddle.net/cn319jsh/

Comment: You might want to use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: How would i do that, im not too familiar with using proxies

Comment: Lots of tutorials around for them. they can be complex. too much for comment block on SO

Comment: But how would i use a proxy to do this example

Comment: To be honest I haven't  spent much time trying to understnd your update. I answered based on original question which showed returning a number. Not entirely clear what you are needing now. Using a Proxy allows you to take your array and add methods to it like a class but the value of the array is still array